# Multiple Apex controllers in Angular app

Tags: remote-action, angular

I have inherited an angular app running in a VisualForce page. There is one apex controller for the page to call the remote actions. I don't see a way to use alternate multiple controllers in this spa architecture. Its not a great design to stuff all the Apex code in one controller. Are there alternatives or best practices for doing this. I'm fairly new to Salesforce.

Answer (score 2):

That's what extensions are for. You can include as many extensions as you like on your page. This is great also for reusable code.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ExtA,ExtB,ExtC">
```

You can also use this syntax even if you use a custom controller:

```
<apex:page controller="Ctrl1" extensions="ExtA,ExtB,ExtC">
```

However, this will require a bit more unusual syntax in your extensions:

```
public class ExtA {
    // Constructor that accepts a Ctrl1 controller
    public ExtA(Ctrl1 ctrl) {
    }
}
```